# Python 3.5.2 NameError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have declared my class `Customer` and are trying to extract data from a class instance and my method `get_place_in_queue` works fine but when I run `get_nr_errands` it craches with the error:

```
"name 'nr_errands' is not defined"
```

My code so far:

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self,index_number,place_in_queue,nr_errands):
        self.index_number=index_number
        self.place_in_queue=place_in_queue
        self.nr_errands=nr_errands

    def get_place_in_queue(self):
        return place_in_queue

    def get_index_number(self):
        return index_number

    def get_nr_errands(self):
        return nr_errands
test=Customer(2,4,5)
test.get_nr_errands()
```

Comment: Shoud be `return(self.nr_errands)`; `nr_errands` is set on the instance in `__init__`, you'll need to grab it through `self`. Similarly for the rest.

Comment: Pretty sure `get_place_in_queue` *doesn't* work, unless you also happen to have a global variable called `place_in_queue`. Of course, you don't actually need any of those methods at all though.

Comment: Don't use parens with `return`, it suggests that they have an effect. Just `return self.nr_errands`.

Comment: You should fix the indentation of the code that's (supposed to be) inside your `__init__` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting to use `self` to access instance variables. You need:

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self,index_number,place_in_queue,nr_errands):
        self.index_number=index_number
        self.place_in_queue=place_in_queue
        self.nr_errands=nr_errands

    def get_place_in_queue(self):
        return self.place_in_queue # <-- here

    def get_index_number(self):
        return self.index_number  # <-- here

    def get_nr_errands(self):
        return self.nr_errands  # <-- here
```